# Multi Threading for Reading/Writing a File in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file

I have a very basic query regarding `File` operations in C++, please forgive me if this a really stupid question.
In my application I have functions which `read/write files`.
I was wondering whether it is possible to *speed up the read/write operation by multi-threading the process.*
I have this doubt because the *CPU might perform better* but the *Hard Disk might perform worse*.
I have the following cases:
1. What if only reading or writing is done at a time by multiple threads, but not both?
2. What if only 1 File is being considered here i.e. read/write is performed on the same file simultaneously by multiple threads?
3. What if multiple files are read/written by multiple threads such that only 1 thread is responsible for a File?
4. What if read & write are done simultaneously by 2 different threads?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading (and asynchronous i/o) are latency-hiding optimizations, not speed enhancements.  Simultaneous access to a single file by multiple threads probably won't get you much.  The place where threading can help you is if you have some other work you want to do (perhaps some user interaction) while you are waiting for the file operation to finish.  It is most helpful in places where one of your operations is blocking (like you are waiting for user input from the keyboard/mouse or are waiting for data or a connection to arrive on a network socket.)  You might, for example, have one thread associated with each socket.

So your case 3:

> What if multiple files are read/written by multiple threads such that
>   only 1 thread is responsible for a File?

is the only one I think is useful to pursue.  And then only if you are sure that there is something else you need to do while the file operation is going on.

Comment: _"Multithreading (and asynchronous i/o) are throughput optimizations"_ -- more correctly, they are purely latency hiding optimizations, much in the sense as you write later in the paragraph (blocking/waiting for an operation to finish). Throughput may, but does not usually increase, it even decreases in some cases.

Comment: Excellent point.  I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might get a speed improvement but there is a lot of overhead involved with threading.  You need to make sure you are loading a significant amount of data or the overheads of inter-thread communication will kill you.

That said you are far better off using the various asynchronous file io options.  They are mostly platform specific but i believe boost::asio can abstract that away for you ...